# What happens if two Reinhardts crash?

Tags: overwatch

If there is a Reinhardt on each team, and they both use their charge ability and run into each other, what happens? Do they both stop as if they ran into a wall, or does whichever one who started the charge first win the shoving contest, or something else?

Comment: They surrender.

Comment: I was just about to ask this

Comment: Hasn't Muselk already done this in an Overwatch Mythbusters?

Comment: @AlexGravely I have no idea.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the Overwatch [Gamepedia page](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Charge):

> If two Charging Reinhardts collide, both Reinhardts will be stunned
>   and their Charges will be cancelled.

Comment: Friendly reminder: Downvote the question if it shows lack of research, but please don't downvote correct answers because of it.

Comment: Can confirm, this happened to me yesterday.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish yea i got a chance to do it yesterday too. its kind of fun to do

Comment: I believe it also does the pinned damage to both reinhardts from my experience, but we might have been damaged from outside sources as well.